# Data health check tool

Tags: validation, drools

I want to perform data health check on huge volume of data, which can be either in RDBMS or cloud file storage like Amazon S3. Which tool would be appropriate for performing data health check, which can give me number of rows, rows not matching a given schema for data type validation, average volume for given time period etc?

I do not want to use any bigdata platform like Qubole or Databricks because of extra cost involved. I found [Drools](https://tools.jboss.org/features/drools.html) which can perform similar operations but it would need reading full data into memory and associate with a POJO before validation. Any alternatives would be appreciated where I do not have to load full data into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid loading full data in memory by implementing the `StatelessKieSession` object of drools. `StatelessKieSession` works only on the current event it does not maintain the state of any event also does not keep objects in the memory. Read more about `StatelessKieSession` [here.](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_statelesskiesession)

Also, you can use Stateful KieSession and give an expiry to an event using the `@expires` declaration which expiries event after the specified time. Read more about `@expires` [here.](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_expires_time_interval)